# Can every simple graph be embedded on a circuit board?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Here, a circuit board is defined as a pair of planar graphs with vertices identified, i.e. a ordered triple $\langle V,E_1,E_2\rangle$ such that there are planar embeddings $h_1,h_2$ for the planar graphs $\langle V,E_1\rangle$ and $\langle V,E_2\rangle$, respectively, such that $h_1(v)=h_2(v)$ for each $v\in V$. Does every simple graph $\langle V,E\rangle$ admit a decomposition $E=E_1\sqcup E_2$ such that $\langle V,E_1,E_2\rangle$ is a circuit board?

If the answer is no, is there a finite $n$ such that every simple graph admits an $n$-layer circuit board decomposition (the generalization to more than two layers should be clear)?

Comment: Note that in practice we are allowed to replace a single edge $u-v$ with a chain of edges $u-x_1-x_2-\ldots-v$, where the $x_i$ are new vertices, and every graph *can* be embedded on a circuit board after a sufficient number of such replacements.

Comment: The condition $h_1(v)=h_2(v)$ is irrelevant, since any two $n$-point sets in the plane ($n$ finite) are topologically equivalent.

Comment: In the second paragraph, by "every planar graph" did you mean "every simple graph"? The number of planar graphs ("layers") needed to cover a given simple graph $G$ is a parameter called the *thickness* of $G$. It can be arbitrarily large: the thickness of the complete graph $K_n$ is at least $\frac{n+2}6$.

Comment: @bof It is true that n point sets are equivalent, but each $h$ is an embedding of the whole graph, not just the vertices, and if you move these points around you might make edges cross, and then it wouldn't be a planar embedding anymore.

Comment: @MJD What if you allow the edges to be arbitrary curves? Doesn't that achieve the same effect?

Comment: If you are allowing the edges to be arbitrary continuous curves (instead of straight lines), moving the points around is not going to make any edges cross. Imagine the graph drawn on a rubber sheet.

Comment: @MJD Could you explain your (positive) answer to this question? I'm guessing you could construct such a mapping if you took a $\Bbb R^3$-embedding of the graph and divided the space into "slabs" $\{x\in\Bbb R^3:a\le x_1<b\}$, mapping every other slab into each of the two planes. But the details of this argument elude me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no. Take $K_{11}$, which has 55 edges. Then one of $E_1$ and $E_2$ has at least $28$ edges. Say $|E_1|\geq 28$. On the other hand, any planar graph satisfies $|E|\leq 3|V|-6$, and so if $(V,E_1)$ was planar, then $28\leq |E_1|\leq 33-6=27$, a contradiction.

Just to complete this answer (even though I like the Ramsey number idea better), for any potential $n$, choose $m$ such that $$\frac{m(m-1)}{6m-12}>n,$$ then run through the above argument using $K_m$.

Comment: I believe the answer to your second question is also no, by taking a large enough $K_m$, but I don't have time to do the calculation right now.

Comment: This is overkill, but you could take $m$ to be the Ramsey number such that any coloring of the edges of $K_m$ with $n$ colors must contain a monochromatic $K_5$.

Comment: But I don't have time to calculate that Ramsey number right now.

Comment: Hahaha ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

I claimed in a comment that if you're allowed to subdivide an edge $u-v$ to $u-x_1-x_2-\cdots-v$ by introducing  new vertices of degree 2, then any graph can be embedded on a circuit board.

The construction is simple.  First embed the graph in a plane.  Some of the edges may cross, and we can assume that the embedding is in so-called "general position" in which  no crossing point is the intersection of more than two edges. (Multiple crossing points can be slightly perturbed to turn into groups of single crossing points.)

Now suppose that edge $a-b$ crosses $c-d$. We want to eliminate this crossing.  Subdivide $c-d$ to $c-c'-d'-d$ so that $a-b$ crosses $c'-d'$, and $c'-d'$ is short enough that it doesn't intersect any other edge. This can be accomplished just by making $c'-d'$ sufficiently short.  Then just move $c'-d'$ to the other side of the circuit board to eliminate the crossing.

[image: diagram of the previous paragraph]

Repeat this process for each of the other crossings.

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that the replacement of edges with chains doesn't change the topology of the graph (i.e. they are homeomorphic as topological structures), so you can rephrase this as "every graph is homeomorphic to a circuit board". (Even non-simple graphs with loops and multi-edges are okay, since you can always add intermediate points to make these graphs simple, and then continue the contstruction normally.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a number n such that you can make an n-layered chip of any graph. Take a complete graph on $R(\underbrace{5,5\dots5,5}_n)$ vertices (R means ramsey's number). Then every n layering of the graph corresponds to a coloring with n colors of that graph. But by ramsey's theorem a complete graph of that size must contain a $K_5$ of only one color. Meaning the chip in the layer corresponding to that color is not planar.

---

I'm really just writing what Bof commented on casteel's answer.