# Graph planarity and electronic circuit boards

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

In another [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618211/can-every-simple-graph-be-embedded-on-a-circuit-board), I found the following definition for 2-layer circuit board decomposition of a graph:

> A circuit board is defined as a pair of planar graphs with vertices
>   identified, i.e. a ordered triple $\langle V,E_1,E_2\rangle$ such that
>   there are planar embeddings $h_1,h_2$ for the planar graphs $\langle
> > V,E_1\rangle$ and $\langle V,E_2\rangle$, respectively, such that
>   $h_1(v)=h_2(v)$ for each $v\in V$.

Similar definition would be for $n$-layer circuit board decomposition.

*Is there an official name for minimal number of circuit board layers needed for graph decomposition?* (for planar graphs, this number would be 1, for nonplanar ones greater than 1)

*Is there an application, or another mathematical result, theorem, etc., involving such number?*

---

EDIT/UPDATE: In this [presentation by David Ippstein](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-GD-02-slides.pdf), I found definition of several related numbers (graph properties):

- Book thickness
- Graph thickness
- Geometric thickness

One can find subtle differences between definitions of these properties in the same paper, as well some computational results.

*Is circuit-board thickness a term different from the three above, or equivalent to one of them?*

Comment: I think thickness is what you're looking for, but since I don't completely understand your definition, this might not be right.

Comment: Yeah, the definition is not perhaps formulated in the best way, but now I see the thickness is what I meant, I found some material here: http://www.emba.uvm.edu/~darchdea/problems/geomthick.html

Comment: I think it's just thickness, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thickness_(graph_theory)